# What is "grep -v '^$' file.txt" doing?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

i have not used `-v` option before with `grep`. The description in help says "Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines."

What does the command `grep -v '^$'  file.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you indicate, `grep` inverts the sense of matching.

See a basic example:

```
$ cat file
1
2

3
4
5
$ grep 3 file
3
$ grep -v 3 file
1
2

4
5
```

In this case, you are matching `^$`. This means: lines that just consist on the beginning of the line and end of the line; that is, empty lines.

Following the previous example:

```
$ grep '^$' b
                      # one empty line
```

Subsequently, `grep -v '^$' file` matches all lines that are not empty:

```
$ grep -v '^$' file
1
2
3             # see how the empty line is not showing
4
5
```